# How to get the key value of an array which is a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string which looks like an array, i saw it as string when i var_dump that variable.?

I have done encoding and decoding of that string, used rtrim and ltrim to trim the white spaces , so that it converts in to array. The var dump show the string as bellow.

```
string(271) "

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tmp_name] => F:\xampp\tmp\phpC90B.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [name] => development-km-technologies.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [size] => 55079
        )

)

"
```

Need the value of any key from the array.

Comment: That very likely was an array at some point. Can you please share the code that is outputting that variable? And also the relevant lines above it.

Comment: So you want the string that looks like an array turned into a real array?

Comment: @Derek yes i want to get the array out of string

Comment: @waterloomatt i am getting the in request after submitting the form which has filepond fileuploader used in it.

Comment: That looks like the contents of the `$_FILES` global array. Something is converting it to a string. Find that, and there you'll find your answer. Can't help anymore without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't remember where I found this code snippet I will post this as a wiki answer.

This code will transform your string array to a real array.

```
function print_r_reverse($input)
{
    $output = str_replace(['[', ']'], ["'", "'"], $input);
    $output = preg_replace('/=> (?!Array)(.*)$/m', "=> '$1',", $output);
    $output = preg_replace('/^\s+\)$/m', "),\n", $output);
    $output = rtrim($output, "\n,");
    return eval("return $output;");
}


$in = '
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tmp_name] => F:\xampp\tmp\phpC90B.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [name] => development-km-technologies.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [size] => 55079
        )

)';


$arr = print_r_reverse(trim($in));
```

It uses eval so don't use it on unsafe strings.

https://3v4l.org/7Kvg8

Comment: getting  syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ';'   error

Comment: There is not a single `<` in your string. Your hiding something